# My Setting tab...missing missing Undue send and enable undue send

Tags: gmail

Here is my problem...Google,  Gmail used to display "**your email has been sent**"  Mine doesn't.
I wanted to stop an email that I just sent...I sent to settings and set it for **30 seconds**.
Why do I not see " your message has been sent?  If I did I would be able to cancel the email.
My Setting tab does not list UNDUE SEND, or ENABLE UNDO SEND.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are in the general tab in settings then it should be the fourth setting immediately under "phone numbers". There should be no reason why you shouldn't be able to see it. If this is a google error then refreshing the page should do it.